# pandas slice rows based on joint condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the below dataframe -df

```
    one  two  three  four  five  six  seven  eight
0   0.1  1.1    2.2   3.3   3.6  4.1    0.0    0.0
1   0.1  2.1    2.3   3.2   3.7  4.3    0.0    0.0
2   1.6  0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
3   0.1  1.2    2.5   3.7   4.4  0.0    0.0    0.0
4   1.7  2.1    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
5   2.1  3.2    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
6   2.1  2.3    3.2   4.3   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
7   2.2  0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
8   0.1  1.8    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
9   1.6  0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0
```

i want to select all rows where **any** columns value is '3.2' but at the same time the selected rows should not have values '0.1' or '1.2'

I can able to get the first part with the below query

```
df[df.values == 3.2]
```

but cannot combine this with the second part of the query (the joint != condition)

i also get the following error

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise != comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

on the larger data set (but not on the smaller replica) when trying the below

```
df[df.values != [0.1,1.2]]
```

//edit:

@pensen, here is the output, rows 1, 15, 27, 35 have values '0.1' though as per the condition they should have been filtered.

```
contains = df.eq(3.2).any(axis=1)
not_contains = ~df.isin([0.1,1.2]).any(axis=1)
print(df[contains & not_contains])
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
1    0.1  2.1  3.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
15   0.1  1.1  2.2  3.2  3.3  3.6  3.7  0.0
27   0.1  2.1  2.3  3.2  3.6  3.7  4.3  0.0
31   3.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
35   0.1  1.7  2.1  3.2  3.6  3.7  4.3  0.0
```

here is the original dataset from 0:36 rows to replicate the above output

```
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
 0   4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1   0.1  2.1  3.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 2   0.1  2.4  2.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 3   2.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 4   4.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 5   1.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 6   0.1  2.1  4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 7   4.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 8   1.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 9   2.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 10  1.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 11  1.1  4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 12  0.1  2.2  3.3  3.6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 13  0.1  1.8  3.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 14  0.1  1.2  1.3  2.5  3.7  4.2  0.0  0.0
 15  0.1  1.1  2.2  3.2  3.3  3.6  3.7  0.0
 16  1.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 17  1.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 18  1.3  2.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 19  0.1  1.2  2.5  3.7  4.4  0.0  0.0  0.0
 20  1.2  4.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 21  4.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 22  1.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 23  0.1  2.2  2.4  2.5  3.7  0.0  0.0  0.0
 24  0.1  2.4  4.3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 25  1.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 26  0.1  1.1  4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 27  0.1  2.1  2.3  3.2  3.6  3.7  4.3  0.0
 28  1.4  2.2  3.6  4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 29  1.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 30  1.2  4.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 31  3.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 32  3.6  4.1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 33  2.1  2.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 34  0.1  1.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 35  0.1  1.7  2.1  3.2  3.6  3.7  4.3  0.0
```

here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qky9kuqzxotvkvn/eq_universe.h5?dl=0) to the actual dataset

Comment: The reason why the solution with `isin` does not work for the given data set seems to be related to a dtype issue, see here fore [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566737/pandas-isin-dtype-dependency-bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance, specially since you mentioned large dataset and if you are looking to exclude just two numbers, here's one approach with array data -

```
a = df.values
df_out = df.iloc[(a == 3.2).any(1) & (((a!=0.1) & (a!=1.2)).all(1))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: a = df.values

In [44]: df.iloc[(a == 3.2).any(1) & (((a!=0.1) & (a!=1.2)).all(1))]
Out[44]: 
   one  two  three  four  five  six  seven  eight
5  2.1  3.2    0.0   0.0     0    0      0      0
6  2.1  2.3    3.2   4.3     0    0      0      0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following in short:

```
df.eq(3.2).any(axis=1) & ~df.isin([0.1, 1.2]).any(axis=1)
```

Or here more explicitly:

```
contains = df.eq(3.2).any(axis=1)
not_contains = ~df.isin([0.1,1.2]).any(axis=1)

print(df[contains & not_contains])
   one    two    three    four    five    six    seven    eight
5  2.1    3.2    0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0    0.0      0.0
6  2.1    2.3    3.2      4.3     0.0     0.0    0.0      0.0
```

Comment: when i run this solution on my larger dataset, the second condition does not gets filtered (although no errors are raised).

Comment: i suspect the all(1) instead of any(1) in the second part of the query makes the difference

Comment: @SirajS. This is a somewhat interesting observation. Do you have an example row which does not get filtered correctly? And note, the 'all' is used differently in the example of Divakar because the values 0.1 and 1.2 are checked explicitly one by one to be **both** unequal (thats why *all* is used). In contrast, in my example, I simply check if **any** of those values are present, and then invert the result. Both ways should come to the same result.

Comment: @pensen, i have added more data in the question. that should allow for replication. please ignore the earlier comment. thankyou

Comment: @SirajS. Strange enough - I get the correct result with your updated dummy data. Only row 31 gets correctly filtered. What pandas version do you use? Btw, my nick is *p**a**nsen* ;-)

Comment: sorry for the mis-spell. I am using pandas 0.19.2, the actual dataset has 191 rows (and is multi index, if that helps :)), i am not able to understand, why it works here with a subset but not on the actual data. Most likely there is some corruption with actual data that is not visible to me. thankyou for your time

Comment: No worries. I'm testing on pandas 0.19.2, too. Multiindex shoudn't interfere there. However, what happens when you reset it via 'reset_index' or remove it completely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137082/discussion-between-siraj-s-and-pansen).

Answer (score 1):

You could just combine the conditions.

```
>>> df[(df == 3.2).any(1) & ~df.isin([0.1, 1.2]).any(1)]

   one  two  three  four  five  six   seven  eight
5  2.1  3.2    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
6  2.1  2.3    3.2   4.3   0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0
```