# pandas isin() returns different result as eq() - floating dtype dependency issue

Tags: python, pandas

pandas' [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method seems to have a dtype dependency (using Python 3.5 with pandas 0.19.2). I just came across this by accident in a related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542790/pandas-slice-rows-based-on-joint-condition/42542883#42542883) where we couldn't explain a non-working behavior for isin. Here is the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.2, 0.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 4.2]])
print(df)

    0       1       2       3       4       5
0   1.2     0.3     1.5     1.4     1.7     4.2

print(df.dtypes)
0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
5    float64
dtype: object

# everything works as expected until here
print(df.isin([1.2, 1.4]))

      0      1      2     3      4      5
0  True  False  False  True  False  False
```

However, when the dtype is casted to `float32`, isin starts to fail:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype("float32"))
print(df.dtypes)

0    float32
1    float32
2    float32
3    float32
4    float32
5    float32
dtype: object

print(df.isin([1.2, 1.4]))
       0      1      2      3      4      5
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Here is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626443/comparing-floats-in-a-pandas-column) on SO.

#### Edit

I understand the floating point complication. However, from a users perspective who wants to employ `isin` as a convenience function for `col1 == 1 | col1 == 3 | col1 == 5` (to simply write `col1.isin([1, 3, 5])`), it may cause unrecognized errors when dtypes are different and no warning is given about the dtype deviation.

What's more, `isin` returns different results in comparison to `df.eq`:

```
print(df.isin([1.2]))

       0      1      2      3      4      5
0  False  False  False  False  False  False

print(df.eq(1.2))

      0      1      2      3      4      5
0  True  False  False  False  False  False
```

This is definitely an unwanted behavior. As [JohnE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877338/johne) pointed out, it seems `df.eq` uses np.isclose whereas `df.isin` does not.

Comment: Try this: `print(1.1 + .1 == 1.2)` ;-)

Comment: Right, good example, it doesn't seem to be related to `isin` then but rather how floating point numbers are stored? Still, while using `isin`, you might run into incorrect results without noticing it.

Comment: this is how floating number comparison is "working" (or not working)...

Comment: Yes. I agree with @MaxU this is "working" as intended.

Comment: similar to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626443/comparing-floats-in-a-pandas-column

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @MaxU @JohnE Updated the question. The main issue here seems the differing results for `df.eq` and `df.isin` as it may deceive unaware users.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Actually I doubt `eq` is using `np.close` but maybe it recasts `1.2` as a float32 or float64 automatically, to correspond to the dtype of df?  Or more likely just does all float comparisons at float64?

Comment: But yeah, maybe you should raise an issue at github.  It does seem like `isin` ought to behave like `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will make it more clear:

```
>>> '%20.18f' % df[0].astype(np.float64)
'1.199999999999999956'

>>> '%20.18f' % df[0].astype(np.float32)
'1.200000047683715820'
```

Generally you don't want to see 18 decimal places so pandas will make reasonable choices about how many decimals to display -- but the difference is still there, albeit invisibly.  So you need to make sure to compare float64 to float64 and float32 to float32.  That's the floating point life we have chosen for ourselves...

Alternatively, if you were comparing to the values one at a time you could use `np.isclose` (after `import numpy as np`) to identify an approximate equality:

```
>>> np.isclose( df.astype(np.float64), 1.2 )
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> np.isclose( df.astype(np.float32), 1.2 )
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

(You don't need the `astype()`, of course, it's just to prove that you would get the same answer for both float32 and float64.)

I don't know if there is a way to make `isin` work in a comparable way so you may have to do something like:

```
>>> np.isclose( df, 1.2 ) | np.isclose( df, 1.4 )
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#try this:
import numpy as np
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float32))
test=[1.2,1.4]
test=test.apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float32))
df.isin(test)
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.